# Moving selected item in JScrollPane to top of list and show remaining items in java

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, selected

I have a list box with scroll pane which loads in an alphabetical list of 100+ song tabs. I can scroll to a song or type the full name to find what I'm looking for in the list.

What I am trying to add is a way to find a song in this long list more easily by just typing in the first letter and then have the index move to that item.  I have accomplished this with the code below but what happens is the first item with letter 'r' (as an example) is identified, selected and then forced to be visible in the pane, but what I would like to do is have that selected item move to the top of the list and drag the next items in line with it.

```
 searchByLetter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        char c;
        String s = (letterField.getText().toUpperCase());
        
        if(s != null) {
            c = s.charAt(0);

            // the line below sends the typed letter to the method listed & returns where in the
            // list the first item with the identified letter is, then the following lines 
            // 'select it' and make it visible in the pane
                              
            indexNumber = GetSongList.getListIndexNumber(c);
        }
        letterField.setText(null);
        list.setSelectedIndex(indexNumber);
        list.ensureIndexIsVisible(indexNumber);
       // what I need now is a way to move this selected item to the top of the list dragging
       // the next items in the list after it
    }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: You can filter the list so that only the items that start with the letter *R* (using your example) appear in the list.  You can further filter the list when you type the second letter.    [JList with Text Field Filter Example](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-swing/list-filter.html)

Comment: Actually I just need the items to all move up rather than filter out the other items, but thanks for the JList text field filtering code.  I now know that I just needed to setViewPosition in the scrollPane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to do is have that selected item move to the top of the list

You don't actually change the data in the model. Instead you change the position of the viewport in the scroll pane:

```
Point p = list.indexToLoction( indexNumber );
scrollPane.getViewport.setViewPosition( p );
```

Or another option is to actually filter the items in the list. You could do this by using a single column `JTable` along with your `JTextField`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a working example.

Comment: Perfect!  That's all I needed.  I knew there had to be a fairly simple (one or two lines of code) way to do this.